# Is there any way to remove the "=" from viewing in inputbox vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have the following code in vb.net, which open Excel file, then ask the user to select Range, the selected range has "=", if I delete it manually the code will continue, if i didn't the i got errors

note that i am using visual studio 2022, and excel 365

`

```
    Private Sub OpenExcelFile()
        ' Open the Excel file
        xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(selectedFile)
        xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        ' Make the Excel application visible
        xlApp.Visible = True


        ' Prompt the user to enter the range they want to select
        Dim rangeInput As String = xlApp.InputBox("Enter the range you want to select (e.g. A1:B2):", "Select Range")

        ' Remove the "=" character from the beginning of the range input, if present
        rangeInput = rangeInput.Replace("=", "")

        ' Select the range
        ' Display the selected range in a label
        MsgBox("You have selected the range: " & rangeInput)


        ' Display the selected range in TextBox2
        TextBox2.Text = rangeInput
    End Sub
```

`

I've tried to trim, replace, and nothing works :(

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the [Application.InputBox method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.InputBox) to obtain a Range then set the `Type` argument equal to the value 8.

```
  Dim app As New Excel.Application
  Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = app.Workbooks.Add

  app.Visible = True
  Dim rng As Excel.Range
  ' Type = 8 tells the InputBox to return a Range object
  ' if the user cancels the input, a null is returned
  rng = TryCast(app.InputBox("Prompt", "Title", Type:=8), Excel.Range)

  ' Excel is the currently active process, bring the form to the front to show message
  Using myProcess As Process = Process.GetCurrentProcess
    AppActivate(myProcess.Id)
  End Using

  MessageBox.Show($"Selected Range = {rng?.Address}")
  wb.Close(False)
  app.Quit()
```

The equal symbol (`=`) you see when using your code is due to the input box displaying the local formula representation of the selected range.  If you want the method to return the formula text set the Type argument to zero.